# How to make a Java program run in the background?

Tags: java

I've looked at tons of different StackOverflow questions, and articles on other websites, but none of them have exactly what I'm looking for.

What I'm attempting to do:

I have a program that needs to sleep for a while, and then check to make sure that a program is still running, then sleep again. I've gotten that part done all fine and dandy, but I'm running into a problem making it run in the background. I'm trying to get it to run with no system tray, no command prompt window, just a process. Is there any way I can do this? It really annoys me having to have a command prompt window open 24/7 for a program as simple as this one, and if anyone could help it would be great!

(Also, note that I'm not talking about compiling from command line, I'm saying after you open the .exe version of the java program, how you could make it open the exe without a command prompt window or GUI)

Thanks!

EDIT: Yes, I am running Windows, and this program will be run solely on Windows OS'.

Comment: 1st hit: http://www.coderanch.com/t/370721/java/java/run-Java-program-background

Comment: What OS are you using?  Windows?

Comment: I think you may run the program as windows service.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a daemon program. The Windows equivalent of a daemon is a Windows Service.

So one solution is to run your program as a Windows Service. It's very simple to convert a command line java program into a service with [ProcRun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html). I just did this last week with a particular program I had - took around half a day, mainly because it was the first time I was doing it.

Making it a Windows Service has the advantage that you can set it to start automatically when the machine boots.

Comment: what if i want to make it with linux base os? how i can do so?

Answer (score 1):

Run this VBS script from the Task Scheduler:

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\myuser\mylib" 
Shell.Run "java.exe MyClass", 0, False
```

Comment: I am a little curious as to why this was down-voted, as it works quite well.

Comment: Me too. The solution above seems obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

Look into javaw, which comes standard with your JRE

Comment: Do you have any links about javaw? I read that in one of my Google Results, but every search for it just contains crap like "What is javaw.exe" "is javaw.exe harmful?" "how to end javaw.exe" etc etc.

Comment: Why don't you read the Java documentation on the Oracle site? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/